# Hypervisor / server that I can install on laptop with three OS'es: Windows 10, Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, laptop, virtualization, hypervisor

I want to install Hypervisor on my Gaming laptop with RTX 2060, so I can have 3 OS'es:

1. Windows 10
2. Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS
3. Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS

I am interested in GPU passthrough of Nvidia RTX 2060 for guest Windows and Ubuntu Desktop and get near-native guest performance if possible. The server should work all the time when the laptop is on in the background. There won't much load on the server. There will be some test environment for WWW, MySQL, load balancer etc.
Mostly I will work at Ubuntu Desktop which will be developer mashine and all Office suit will be there. Ubuntu will be main OS, but sometimes I would like to have also Windows on to run Windows specific apps, Games.
At the peak, I will have 3 OS'es running simultaneously and switch between them easily.
I want to work directly on the laptop to operate on the same machine with three OS'es with GUI. My CPU is a i7-9750H with VT-d support.

Is it possible to have Hypervisor as separate system and 3 guest OS'es? Is it worth doing those considering pitfalls? How can I do that?
Or maybe it is better to have Ubuntu Desktop as Hypervisor and two Guests: Ubuntu Server and Windows 10?

Comment: GPU passthrough requires processor support.  Does your processor support it?  You should [edit] your question so it includes the necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: Your processor supports VT-d, which means it supports PCIe passthrough, but the next question I would have is what sort of workloads specifically you expect to run and which hypervisor you plan to use.  Please be as specific as possible and indicate what your host OS will be.

Comment: Can you run a Hypervisor like ESXi as the main operating system and run through virtual machines, sure you can, but you would need additional hardware to access those VMs remotely.  DX and Vulcan support within any hypervisor is limited.  VMWare supports DX 11.1 I believe, if your application requires DX12, then they won't work.  Doesn't sound like that workload will work for you within a VM. Running 3 VMs continuously requires dedicated hardware, that typically isn't a laptop, running a mobile processor with a mobile GPU.